# Is it possible to serve different databases to different users with the same application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core, iis, web-hosting

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC application, hosted with IIS.
I want to serve multiple different users and I would like them to each access their own database.

Im currently looking at the appSettings.Json file and here I found

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Am I correct to think that this will end up with every user connecting to my application, they all will be using the  "XXXXX" Database?

How / Where can I get started to configure that a specific user has a specific database? ( If this is even possible?)

Warm regards

Comment: https://stackify.com/writing-multitenant-asp-net-core-applications/ - does this answer your question?

Comment: I will look into it, thank you for your effort!

Comment: If you want to connect to different database, you should create different Dbcontexts and add them in configureServices. Then choose which Dbcontext to use according to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many DbContext as you want with different connection strings. Like this in your services:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => {
     options.UseSqlServer("[ConnectionString]");
});
```

Comment: How can I apply this for different users in the SAME startup.cs file ?